# QR Codes by DelphiZXingQRCode are not always decodable, how to implement the solution?

Tags: delphi, qr-code

The question [QR Codes encoded by DelphiZXingQRCode not decodable with ErrorCorrectionLevel > Low 1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44160153/2292722) is solved. I have exactly the same problem, but I cannot implement the solution, because there are missing sections: The method GenerateQRCode is not described. It is not clear to me, where the function TErrorCorrectionLevel.GetBits has to be used. The declaration of the variable fOrdinal is not clear. 
I tried several times to guess the missing sections of the solution.

Comment: Have you downloaded the original source from github?

Comment: Sorry, this isn't a suitable question for this site. Please read the articles at the [help].

Comment: @Tom: I downloaded the original source of DelphiZXingQRCode. I think the solution was not uploaded.

Comment: Well, it was @Dsm who suggested the download, and I agree. The idea being that you apply the changes suggested in the question/answer you refererred to (and I just linked to), to the source from Github. I have no idea if the Github source is updated or not. If not, perhaps you may want to update it.

Comment: @Tom: In the linked topic is a solution which has to be merged with the original. However, the code of the solution is not complete. The author found the solution himself, but he only gave parts of the code. I would like to have the merged file or some more code of the solution to merge by myself. I tried to merge, but I failed several times.

Comment: Sorry to hear about the difficulty. Perhaps you can enter a comment to the person who posted that solution, and ask him for further info. I just checked when @Mat was around, and it was some 6 hours ago.

Comment: JC Boggio seems to have implemented this using Mat's solution as a starting point (see comments after solution). Maybe he can help too.

Answer (score 0):

Solved: Missing code for the merging:

```
(* Start Declaration of fOrdinal; Constructor added, use of GetBits *)
TErrorCorrectionLevel = class
private
  fOrdinal: Integer;
  function GetBits:Integer;
public
  constructor Create(ordinalValue: Integer); reintroduce;
  procedure Assign(Source: TErrorCorrectionLevel);
  property Bits: Integer read GetBits;
end;
(* End Declaration of fOrdinal; Constructor added, use of GetBits *)


(* Start of modified GenerateQRCode, Level is taken from Input-Parameter *)
function GenerateQRCode(const Input: WideString; EncodeOptions: Integer; AErrorCorrectionLevel:Integer): T2DBooleanArray;
var
  Encoder: TEncoder;
  Level: TErrorCorrectionLevel;
  QRCode: TQRCode;
  X: Integer;
  Y: Integer;
begin
  Level := TErrorCorrectionLevel.Create(AErrorCorrectionLevel);
  Encoder := TEncoder.Create;
  QRCode := TQRCode.Create;
  try
    Encoder.Encode(Input, EncodeOptions, Level, QRCode);
    if (Assigned(QRCode.FMatrix)) then
    begin
      SetLength(Result, QRCode.FMatrix.FHeight);
      for Y := 0 to QRCode.FMatrix.FHeight - 1 do
      begin
        SetLength(Result[Y], QRCode.FMatrix.FWidth);
        for X := 0 to QRCode.FMatrix.FWidth - 1 do
        begin
          Result[Y][X] := QRCode.FMatrix.Get(Y, X) = 1;
        end;
      end;
    end;
  finally
    QRCode.Free;
    Encoder.Free;
    Level.Free;
  end;
end;
(* End of modified GenerateQRCode, Level is taken from Input-Parameter *)
```

Comment: An answer should not just contain a link to an external resource, which could become unavailable at any time.

Comment: @Peter, better use `case` switch there.

Comment: @Victoria, I could not find out what you exactly mean and how to do it. Where can I find help?